# How can I format String '31/12/2023 00:00:00' to 'dd/MM/yyyy' as DateTime then String in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime, date-format

I stored the date in database as String and call it via model `String? myDate;`, the data save as `31/12/2023 00:00:00`.
I want to dispaly in `Text` widget as `31/12/2023` not `31/12/2023 00:00:00` so I tried to covnert `String` to `DateTime` then to `String` again but the resutl is `2023-12-31 00:00:00.000`

```
var date = '31/12/2023 00:00:00';
DateTime parseDate = intl.DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseDate.toString());
print(inputDate);
//output: 2023-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

How to achive my goal?

Comment: same Question hope to find out the solution!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to play around your `String` and convert it to format that intl.DateFormat can use it.

This code solves my problem:

try it in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;

void main() {
    var date = '31/12/2023 00:00:00';
    String dateWithT = "${date.substring(6, 10)}-${date.substring(3, 5)}-${date.substring(0, 2)}T00:00:00.000000Z";
    DateTime parseDate = intl.DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(dateWithT);
    var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseDate.toString());
    var outputFormat = intl.DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
    var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
    print(outputDate);
}
```

Comment: @RohanJariwala read carefully my answer and test it you will get the result as Laim desired. Also you answer does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just call these methods on the `DateTime`, its self-explanatory:

```dart
void main() {
  var date = '31/12/2023 00:00:00';
  DateTime parseDate = intl.DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
  
  final formattedDate = "${parseDate.day}/${parseDate.month}/${parseDate.year}";
  print(formattedDate);
}
```

Prints:

```
31/12/2023
```

Comment: 31-12-2023 not as 31/12/2023

Comment: @Liam this is also solve the problem but change - with / as `final formattedDate =
                              "${parseDate.day}/${parseDate.month}/${parseDate.year}";`

I will delete my answer but I hope someone to get another idea from my code. sometimes when you read anything you got another idea so I will keep my answer for others.

Comment: @Liam I edited my answer for the desired output.

Comment: Yes  this answer is better and short but I got a problem when i i have a date 01/07/2023 so this answer make it 1/7/2023 while i need it as 01/07/2023. Thank you for both. @AbdullahBahattab answer for my problem